# FFMPEG - How to get exactly file name and add a drawtext in each output video of a rendering queue

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need some help with this FFMPEG code running in Windows:

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set INPUT=D:\In

Set OUTPUT=D:\Out

for %%a in ("%INPUT%\*.*") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "drawtext=text=${%%a}:x=105:y=120:fontfile=font/impact.ttf:fontsize=25:fontcolor=white" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2000k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast "%OUTPUT%/%%~na.mp4"
```

I have some video files like `The.Input.Video.mp4` in `INPUT` folder and I want to create output videos with the filename text added, so I use `drawtext=text=${%%a}`. The problem is, the received text for each video shows as "`D:\FFMPEG\BIN\The.Input.Video.MP4`" (It contains the file path, the "." and the mp4 suffix). How can I remove them and get the filename as "The Input Video" only. Thanks alot.

Comment: Use `%%~nxa` in the text field

Comment: read the output of `for /?` - especially the "modifier" part.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible substitutions for these types of variables. (note: one `%` is in cmd, in a batch-file you need two `%%`)

```
%~I Expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (").
%~fI    Expands %I to a fully qualified path name.
%~dI    Expands %I to a drive letter only.
%~pI    Expands %I to a path only.
%~nI    Expands %I to a file name only.
%~xI    Expands %I to a file extension only.
%~sI    Expanded path contains short names only.
%~aI    Expands %I to file attributes of the file.
%~tI    Expands %I to date/time of the file.
%~zI    Expands %I to size of the file.
%~$PATH:I   Searches the directories listed in the PATH environment variable and expands %I to the fully qualified name of the first one found. If the environment variable name is not defined or the file is not found by the search, then this modifier expands to the empty string.


The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

%~dpI   Expands %I to a drive letter and path only.
%~nxI   Expands %I to a file name and extension only.
%~fsI   Expands %I to a full path name with short names only.
%~dp$PATH:i Searches the directories listed in the PATH environment variable for %I and expands to the drive letter and path of the first one found.
%~ftzaI Expands %I to a DIR like output line.
In the above examples, %I and PATH can be replaced by other valid values. The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid FOR variable name. Picking uppercase variable names like %I makes it more readable and avoids confusion with the modifiers, which are not case sensitive.
```

So what you need to get only the file name is `%%~na`

If you also want to replace all `.` with spaces you need to store the name to a regular variable (`set "fileName=%%~na"`) and then use it like this: `%fileName:.= %`. Because you want to do this within the for-loop you have to use call or delayedExpansion.

*< EDIT: added complete example >*

```
@ECHO OFF&Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set INPUT=D:\In
Set OUTPUT=D:\Out
for %%a in ("%INPUT%\*.*") DO ( 
    set "filename=%%~na"
    ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "drawtext=text=!fileName:.= !:x=105:y=120:fontfile=font/impact.ttf:fontsize=25:fontcolor=white" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2000k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast "%OUTPUT%/%%~na.mp4" 
)
```

*< /EDIT >*

*< EDIT: example for replacing/removing multiple characters >*

```
set "fileName=!fileName:.= !"
set "fileName=!fileName:-= !"
set "fileName=!fileName:[= !"
```

Just add this after setting the fileName to `%%~na`.

*< /EDIT >*

Comment: I tried this one but it doesn't work:

@ECHO OFF 

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

Set INPUT=D:\In 

Set OUTPUT=D:\Out 

for %%a in ("%INPUT%*.*") DO ( 

set "filename=%%~na"

 %fileName:.= % 

ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "drawtext=text=%filename%:x=105:y=120:fontfile=font/impact.ttf:fontsize=25:fontcolor=white" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2000k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast "%OUTPUT%/%%~na.mp4" ) 
Could you please help me fix this, thank you so much. – ivodi 15 hours ago

Comment: It's difficult to read your code like this, but I think I found 2 mistakes:
- I wrote "*use* it like this", which means you should write ```%fileName:.= %``` instead of ```%fileName%``` or set it again with ```set "fileName=%fileName:.= %"```
- I also wrote "Because you want to do this within the for-loop you have to use call or delayedExpansion." -> simplest solution: write ```setlocal enableDelayedExpansion``` at the beginning of your batch-file (after echo off) and then replace every ```%fileName...%``` and other variables you may set in the for-loop with ```!fileName...!```.

Comment: maybe implementing and showing is the better explanation ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've fixed the code. Now I have another problem, that is my input filenames have other texts I want to remove besides "." (such as "-","["). Unfortunately I can't set all of those texts inside !fileName...! of the loop. I tried !fileName:.= ,-= ,[= ! but it doesn't work:((

Comment: You can only execute one replacement at once, so you need a command for each replacement. For better readability I added the code to the answer.